# Modify Excel Sheet with data from XML using XSLT

Tags: excel, xml, xslt

I need to provide a report in Excel format from a Template Excel and an XML file that contains the data (created from SQL request: report_data.xml). But I can't use XPath expression to navigate through an Excel sheet, and I can't select a specific row in the template to duplicate with the data from the report_data.xml

In order to achieve this, I've first "unzipped" the Excel template in order to have access to the individual sheets in .xml format. At the same time I'm setting "source" files that will be used as the default file (eg: source-sheet1.xml, source-sharedstring.xml, ...) to create the new populated files.

I can't find a way to select a specific row in the template to duplicate with the data from the xml.

[TemplateSource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxWiC.png)
[Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjxiM.png)
I've tested this using Xalan 2.7.2 and Saxon 9.7.0.15 //
XSLT 1.0

source-sheet1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<worksheet  xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" 
            xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" 
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
            mc:Ignorable="x14ac" 
            xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac">
    <dimension ref="A1:G1"/>
    <sheetViews>
        <sheetView tabSelected="1" workbookViewId="0">
            <selection activeCell="B5" sqref="B5"/>
        </sheetView>
    </sheetViews>
    <sheetFormatPr baseColWidth="10" defaultColWidth="9.140625" defaultRowHeight="15" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"/>
    <sheetData>
        <row r="1" spans="1:7" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
            <c r="A1" t="s">
                <v>0</v>
            </c><c r="B1" t="s">
                <v>1</v>
            </c><c r="C1" t="s">
                <v>2</v>
            </c><c r="D1" t="s">
                <v>3</v>
            </c><c r="E1" t="s">
                <v>4</v>
            </c><c r="F1" t="s">
                <v>5</v>
            </c><c r="G1" t="s">
                <v>6</v>
            </c>
        </row>
    </sheetData>
    <pageMargins left="0.7" right="0.7" top="0.75" bottom="0.75" header="0.3" footer="0.3"/>
</worksheet>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math"
    xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"
    xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:redirect="org.apache.xalan.xslt.extensions.Redirect"
    xmlns:office="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"
    xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
    extension-element-prefixes="redirect"
    exclude-result-prefixes="fo fn math set redirect office r ss">

<xsl:variable name="SrcSheet1"  select="document('XLSX/source-sheet1.xml')"/>

<xsl:template match="Report">
    <xsl:call-template name="Test1"/>
</xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="Test1">
            <xsl:for-each select="$SrcSheet1/Worksheet/sheetData/row">
                <xsl:message>
                    row = <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                    colcount= <xsl:value-of select="count(./c)"/>
                </xsl:message>  
            </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

report_data.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report attrib1="foo" ...>
    <Data attrib1="foo" ...>
       <SubData attrib1="foo" ... />
       ...
    </Data>
    ...
</Report>
```

I would like to be able to "read" the source-sheet1.xml and copy the rows in it, and the change the values in each columns (when needed; styles and polices depends if it's the 1st , 2nd, ... row for the same data) with the data from report_data.xml

If this is not the way to generate a report in excel from data in xml with different style depending on the "position" of the data in the excel file.

Comment: Picture of Template Excel and Report Excel added.
The problem I've got lies more with the navigation inside the excel sheet than the report_data.xml. The last one I can get all the data I want using Xpath expressions without any issues (this is why I didn't expand much on this file)

Comment: One issue you have in your XSLT is that you have not accounted for namespaces. In source-sheet1.xml the `Worksheet` element and its descendants are in the namespace  `http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main`. In practical terms, you should change your xsl:for-each to `<xsl:for-each select="$SrcSheet1/office:Worksheet/office:sheetData/office:row">`